# $id not being collected from the uri segment

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter, crud

The issue that I am having is when I go `http://domain/admin/editpage/"id"` I get 404 not found and I cannot understand why the id is not being passed into the form:

**Controller**

```
if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Editsale extends CI_Controller {

function __construct() {
parent::__construct();

}

function index() {
    if(!$this->session->userdata('logged_in')) {
        redirect('admin/home');
    }

        $data['title'] = "Edit Sale Name";
        $data['sales_pages'] = $this->sales_model->getSalesPages();
        $data['cms_pages'] = $this->navigation_model->getCMSPages();
        $id = $this->uri->segment(3); 
                    $data['id'] = $id;
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('name', 'Name', 'trim|required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('location', 'Location', 'trim|required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('bedrooms', 'Bedrooms', 'trim|is_natural');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('bathrooms', 'Bathrooms', 'trim');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('condition', 'Condition', 'trim');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('description', 'Description', 'trim');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('price', 'Price', 'trim');

        if($this->form_validation->run() === TRUE) {
            $data = array(
            'name' => $this->input->post('name', TRUE),
            'location' => $this->input->post('location', TRUE),
            'bedrooms' => $this->input->post('bedrooms', TRUE),
            'bathrooms' => $this->input->post('bathrooms', TRUE),
            'condition' => $this->input->post('condition', TRUE),
            'description' => $this->input->post('description', TRUE),
            'price' => $this->input->post('price', TRUE)
            );

            $this->sales_model->updateSale($data);

            $data['sales'] = $this->sales_model->getSalesPages();   

            redirect('admin/addsale' , $data);

            $this->session->set_flashdata('success', 'Page Saved'); 
        }else{
            $data['content'] = $this->load->view('admin/editsale', NULL, TRUE);
            $this->load->view('template', $data);
        }


}

}
```

**Model**

```
class Sales_model extends CI_Model
{

function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
}

function getSalesPages() {

        $query = $this->db->get('sales');
        if($query->num_rows() > 0) return $query->result();

    }

function addSale($data) {

$this->db->insert('sales', $data);
return;
}   

function updateSale($id, $data) {

    $this ->db->where('id', $id);
    $this->db->update('sales', $data);
}
 }
```

**View**

```
 <?php
//Setting form attributes
$formEditSale = array('id' => 'editSale', 'name' => 'editSale');
$formName = array('id' => 'name', 'name' => 'name');
$formLocation = array('id' => 'location', 'name' => 'location');
$formBedrooms = array('id' => 'bedrooms','name' => 'bedrooms');
$formBathrooms = array('id' => 'bathrooms','name' => 'bathrooms');
$formCondition = array('id' => 'condition','name' => 'condition');
$formDescription = array('id' => 'description','name' => 'description');
$formPrice = array('id' => 'price','name' => 'price');
?>
<section id = "validation"><?php echo validation_errors();?></section>

<?php
 echo form_open('admin/editsale/'.$id, $formEditsale);
 echo form_fieldset();
 echo form_label('Name:', 'name');
 echo form_input($formName);
 echo form_label ('Location', 'location');
 echo form_input($formLocation);
 echo form_label ('Bedrooms', 'bedrooms');
 echo form_input($formBedrooms);
 echo form_label ('Bathrooms', 'bathrooms');
 echo form_input($formBathrooms);
 echo form_label ('Condition', 'condition');
 echo form_input($formCondition);
 echo form_label ('Price', 'price');
 echo form_input($formPrice);
 echo form_label ('Description', 'description');
 echo form_textarea($formDescription);
 echo form_submit('submit','Submit');
 echo form_fieldset_close();
 echo form_close();
```

**.htaccess**

```
# Customized error messages.
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php

# Set the default handler.
 DirectoryIndex index.php

# Various rewrite rules.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|css|js|images|files|scripts|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>

# Set timezone
SetEnv TZ Pacific/Auckland
```

Comment: This is more like a rewrite problem to me

Comment: I assume that @thephpdeveloper is correct. Check your CI routes.

Comment: is it working if you use /index.php ,if it works , its a problem with rewrites for sure...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using the default `index` method, you need to either include it in your uri:

`http://domain/admin/editsale/index/$id`

Or set a route:

`$route['admin/editsale/(:num)'] = 'admin/editsale/index/$1';`

Or use another method:

`http://domain/admin/editsale/edit/$id`

The `index` segment is only optional by default if you are not passing any parameters through the uri.

`http://domain/admin/editsale`

Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add

```
$data['id']=$id;
```

in your controller to get it worked in the view.